# For auditing purpose, need to provide all the patches applied through zypper patch command. How to list all the patches installed in last 3 months

Tags: opensuse, suse, zypper

We are using below command to install patches regularly

`zypper patch -g security`

Now we need to audit all the installed patches in last 3 months. Is there a way to get a list of all installed patches in the system. We are using Suse 12 Sp5. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tux > zypper list-patches --all --cve

Issue | No. | Patch | Category | Severity | Status
------+---------------+-------------------+-------------+-----------+----------
cve | CVE-2015-0287 | SUSE-SLE-Module.. | recommended | moderate | needed
cve | CVE-2014-3566 | SUSE-SLE-SERVER.. | recommended | moderate | not needed
[...]
```

Source is chapter 6.1.3.2 / page 49 of [Administration Guide - SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP5](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/12-SP5/pdf/book-sle-admin_color_en.pdf)

Not sure of this apply to opensuse also.

Answer (score 1):

To list all available patches, you could use

```
zypper search --type patch
```

and to limit these results to installed patches only, please use

```
zypper search --type patch --installed-only
```

Due to missing hints in the docs, I doubt that it's currently possible to limit the results to "security" patches only, so checking the type of a patch would need to be done in a separate step.